# I want to get Text that is displaying in console and use that text for login Username in LoginPage

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver

I want str that is printed in  console output  and use that text into Login Page as username?
I get the text displayed in console , but how to call that same text in login page.

```
WebElement path = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form/div[2]/div[1]/div[6]/div[1]/ul/li[1]"));

String str = path.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class='entity-value']")).getText();
System.out.println(str);
```

Comment: str is showing you required username then what are the problem you are facing, just put this str as it mentioned in my answer or tell us more like what stops you to do so,... is your login function is in another class etc

Comment: yes loginpage is different class

Comment: user page is another class having method where i will findelement and get the text from popup screen.

Comment: But i have com.pages.tests as different package , where i will call this userpage method

Comment: Then write a testcase in a common class amd funtion and call both of function in that testcase .. are you using POM framework?

Comment: Then there must a package as something like testcases where you write the testcases as script. now call first class function from which you can retrive the username and then pass it to login page by calling it's function... if you need to redirect the URL then also you .. it's actually also depend upon your busineess logic

Answer (score 0):

First of all your question is incomplete and unclear.
Still I am trying to answer as per my understanding.

I assuming your able to getText from your above code.(If not then please share the HTML code of where from your are extracting the username in first place)
Now as per your code the Text is assign to String str.

Now you just need to pass this try to Your Login Page user name Text box as below(For complete loctor code please share the HTML code of your login page)

```
driver.findElement(By."YOUR LOCATOR").sendKeys(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are wrong in cssSelector, because the structure of cssSelector like your code above can be:

```
By.cssSelector(".entity-value")
```